# Javascript TypeError: callback is not a function - how do i fix this?

Tags: javascript, object, callback

How do i fix this?

Here is the problem:

Implement a function "mapById", which, when given a  array of objects, returns an object, where the keys are the ids of the input objects and the values are the  corresponding input objects.

For example:

```
mapById([{id: 102, name: "Alice"},
        {id: 205, name: "Bob", title: "Dr."},
        {id: 592, name: "Claire", age: 32}]);
```

Returns:

```
{
102: {id: 102, name: "Alice"},
205: {id: 205, name: "Bob", title: "Dr."},
592: {id: 592, name: "Claire", age: 32}
}
```

var key = callback(item);
              ^
TypeError: callback is not a function

```
function mapById(list, callback) {
    var obj = {};
    list.forEach(function(item) {
        var key = callback(item);
        if (obj[key]) {
            obj[key] = obj[key].concat(item);
        } else {
            obj[key] = [item];
        }
    });
    return obj;
}

console.log(mapById(input));
```

Comment: where are you calling `mapById`?

Comment: You fix it by providing a proper function in the caller.

Comment: format your code, i think you will find the issue.

Comment: Can you send us the segment where you call the mapById function?

Comment: I'm closing this thread and replacing it with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48481248/javascript-how-to-iterate-through-an-array-of-object-and-create-a-new-object

Answer (score 7):

#### Problem:

The error that you're having is that when you defined the function, you gave it two parameters: `list`, `callback`

```js
function mapById(list, callback) {}
```

However, when you **called** the function you only gave it **ONE** parameter: `input`

```js
console.log(mapById(input));
```

Hence, when your code is executed and it reaches this part of the function `var key = callback(item);` it throws and exception because callback is **undefined** since you did not pass in a second argument.

#### Solution:

There are **many** ways to fix your problem. One solution is to simply call the callback **inside** when you first declared `mapById`.

Then **move** the code logic that returns the object as your **second** parameter when you **CALL** mapById, **NOT** when you declare it.

E.g.

```js
function mapById(list, callback) {
    var obj = {};
    return callback(item);
}

console.log(mapById(input, function() {
    // logic goes here
}));
```

Note I personally would not structure it that way, as a callback is unnecessary, but I am showing you how it can be done with a callback.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how you would structure the code without a callback?

Answer (score 1):

You call this function like this,

```
mapById(my_list, function(){
    return "my_key"
});
```

The error you get says that you have either passed a wrong argument as the second argument, or you haven't passed a second argument at all.

However, the term callback does not make sense here. Callback functions are used to signal the caller function that the called function has finished executing.

For your case, I would suggest to use a name like, `getKey` or `getKeyByListItem` etc.