# JavaScript -- how to iterate through an array of objects to create a new object whose key is the value of the original object's initial key/value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Here is my situation:

I have to implement a function "mapById", which, when given an array of objects, returns an object, where the keys are the ids of the input objects and the values are the corresponding input objects.

```
var input = [{id: 102, name: "Alice"},
             {id: 205, name: "Bob", title: "Dr."},
             {id: 592, name: "Claire", age: 32}];

console.log(mapById(input));
```

should give the result below:

```
102: {id: 102, name: "Alice"},
205: {id: 205, name: "Bob", title: "Dr."},
592: {id: 592, name: "Claire", age: 32}
```

Here is my function thus far:

```
function mapById(list) {
    var obj = {};
    var objectKey = '';
    list.forEach(function(item) {
        objectKey = (Object.values(item)[0]);
        var obj = {[objectKey]: item};
    });
    return obj;
}
```

I can get a new key/value pair for each object in the original array but I can't figure out how to add each new key/value pair to the new object.

```
ObjectKey: 102
item: { id: 102, name: 'Alice' }
obj: { '102': { id: 102, name: 'Alice' } }
ObjectKey: 205
item: { id: 205, name: 'Bob', title: 'Dr.' }
obj: { '205': { id: 205, name: 'Bob', title: 'Dr.' } }
ObjectKey: 592
item: { id: 592, name: 'Claire', age: 32 }
obj: { '592': { id: 592, name: 'Claire', age: 32 } }
```

How can i fix this? If this was an array I could use the 'push' method. Is there a similar method for objects? Do I need a closure? I know this is basic stuff but I'm quite new to javascript.

Thanks.

Comment: edited the question for clarity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are actually quite close:

```
function mapById(list) {
    var obj = {};
    list.forEach(function(item) {
        obj[item.id] = item;
    });
    return obj;
}
```

How i would do that:

```
 const result = Object.assign(...input.map(el => ({[el.id] : el})));
```

Comment: Wow, your approach is like black magic for me. Can you describe how it works, please?

Comment: @terales it maps the array to an array of key-value pair like objects and unifies these objects by spreading them into Object.assign

Comment: But `Object.entries` returns an array, how do you cast it to object?

Comment: @terales ouch. Shoulve been `Object.assign`, sorry. Good night everyone :/

Comment: oh, thanks. Now it's clear. I thought it was some clever trick and it was interesting to get over it :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var input = [{id: 102, name: "Alice"},
             {id: 205, name: "Bob", title: "Dr."},
             {id: 592, name: "Claire", age: 32}]
             
var output = input.reduce(function(accumulator, item) {
  accumulator[item.id] = item
  return accumulator
}, {})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var output = input.reduce(function(m,x,i) {
  m[x.id] = x
  return m
}, {})
```

The `reduce` function allows you to build a single object as you iterate an array. Notice the last parameter `{}` which initialises `m` to an empty object.

Comment: The code posted is effectively identical to that in @terales answer, yet more terse.  There is no value added here.

Comment: I don't see any other answer! I'm using the app